# Make a chi-2 test and 3d spectral test with python LCG

Tags: python, math

I'm developping for my math stuff but I'm blocked. Here is the statement :

We denote by U and V two sequences of random floats, obtained using a random type generator in the interval [0,1].

If we combine the U and V sequences according to the transformation: Z = m + σ √(−2lnU) sin (2πV). We obtain a variable Z according to the law N (m, σ).

I want to obtain a normal distribution with mean m = 3 and standard deviation 1.

So, I've generated my array of 30 000 Z floats with :

```
def generateFloat(tr):
    list = []
    for i in range(tr):
        list.append(random.uniform(0,1))
    return list

def generateZ(nb,m,o):
    U = generateFloat(nb)
    V = generateFloat(nb)

    tab = []
    for i in range(nb):
        Z = m+(o*sqrt(-2*log(U[i])) * sin (2*pi*V[i]) )
        tab.append(Z)
    return tab
```

I would like to make the chi-square test and do the 3D spectral test. Actually my chi-square test give me weird values...

```
def khi2(x):
    S = 0
    E = len(x)/(max(x))
    print(max(x)-1)
    for i in range(max(x)):
        O = x[i]
        S += ((O-E)**2)/E
    return S
```

and for my 3d spectral test i have this code :

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.axes()

num_bars = 30000
x_pos = genererFlottant(num_bars)
y_pos = genererFlottant(num_bars)

ax.scatter(x_pos, y_pos)
pyplot.show()
```

I think but i'm not sure about values that i obtened are good on my graph... And this isn't in 3d. So, i don't think it's a good graph

I don't know if i'm doing right. If someone can help me with something, i take any help that i can have :/

thank you.